# Open modal from another suburl

Tags: html, razor, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, blazor

I have the following some clickable sub list of a button which is in the navbar of the website having some modals in different urls such as `url.com/mystock#modal-batch-stock-add`.

Navbar button list

```
<div class="btn">
    <a class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> 
    </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" style="">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">First Link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Second Link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Third Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

A modal example which is in `mystock.razor` (think of it as just as html typically).

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-target="#modal-batch-stock-add"><!--!--><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> ABCDE-DeMO-MODAL</button>
```

I wish I open the modals which are in different sub-html files and place them in `dropdown-items' href`s. I thought I would write like `a class="dropdown-item"  href="url.com/mystock#modal-batch-stock-add"` but on the address bar when I enter `url.com/mystock#modal-batch-stock-add` doesn't retrieve the modal.

Comment: I'm a little lost on your explanation, but what I think you need is a modal doalog framework that you launch your forms into.  Here's a link to my modal dialog implementation in Blazor that shows you how to build a (relatively simple) modal dialog framework - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5286721/A-Simple-Bootstrap-Modal-Dialog-for-Blazor.  Alternatively there's a slightly different implementation here at Blazored - https://github.com/Blazored/Modal.

Comment: I advise against directly using bootstrap in your app. Take a look at [Blazorise](https://blazorise.com/docs/faq/). You can find the modal component [here](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/modal/).